# $f(x_0)=0 \forall f \in X^*$ then $x_0=0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a vector space of infinite dimension (possibly) and $x_0 \in X$.

I would like to show that if $f(x_0)=0 \forall f \in X^*$ then $x_0=0$.
So the first intuition would be to pick a function such as $Id_X$ but this is not even into the dual $X^*$.

**Edit :**

Actually $X^*$ was the topological dual, so containing the continuous functions (Sorry, I totally forgot that this could be confused with the algebraic dual, but actually, the answers still helped me for this, so thanks).

Comment: Hint: Hahn-Banach

Comment: Do you know that for each $x_0 \in X$, there is an $f \in X^*$ such that $f(x_0) = \Vert x_0 \Vert?$

Comment: Well, if $X$ is normed then $X^*$ refers to the *continuous* dual space and thus we need something like Hahn-Banach. But if there is no norm on $X$ then $X^*$ refers to the *algebraic* dual space, in which case we just find a Hamel basis $\mathcal{B}$ and let $f(b_0)=1$ for some $b_0$ in the nonzero basis expansion of $x_0$ and $f(b)=0$ for all other elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: If there is no topology, then tag (functional-analysis) should be removed.

Comment: @roi_saumon Try to use the Hahn Banach theorem (It shouldn't be that hard, but this depend on what form of the Hahn Banach theorem you're using). If you fail to do so I would ask a separate question about the case where $X$ is not just a vector space but a Banach space instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the statment is not necessarily true without assuming the axiom of choice. But if we assume it, then $X$ has a basis. It's easy to dedudce from this that, if $x_0\neq0$, then $X$ has a basis $B$ such that $x_0\in B$. Now, consider $\varphi\in X^*$ which maps $x_0$ into $1$ and all other elements of $B$ into $0$.

Comment: Is it clear that $\varphi$ is continuous? Edit: I think it's not but also the OP didn't specify any topology so I guess this answer is valid.

Comment: Did you mention continuity in your question. Actually, did you assume anything about $X$ other than the fact that it is a vector space?

Comment: That's not my question. Also you're right. I suppose it's the "functional analysis"- tag and the notation of $X$ (instead of $V$) for a vector space that made me think unconsciously that the question is about Banach spaces.

Comment: @Yanko I'm so sorry. It was automatic for me that you were the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

I take the hypothesis that $X^*$ is [the algebraic dual space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) as you don’t mention any norm or something similar.

Suppose that $x_0 \neq 0$ and complement it with $(y_i)_{i \in I}$ to get a basis $\mathcal B=(x_0,(y_i)_{i \in I})$. **This uses axiom of choice.**

Then define $f \in X^*$ on that basis by $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(y_i)=0$ for $i \in I$.

You’re done.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify any topology, so it could well be that $X^*$ is supposed to be the algebraic dual of $X$. As a matter of interest, *if* $X$ is a Banach space and $X^*$ is supposed to be the space of continuous linear functionals, then the construction in the other two answers, "choose a basis and send one basis element to $1$, the others to $0$", does *not* necessarily give a continuous functional:

Say $\Lambda$ is an unbounded linear functional on $X$ and let $Y$ be the nullspace of $\Lambda$. Let $B_0$ be a Hamel basis for $Y$, and let $B=B_0\cup\{x_0\}$ where $\Lambda x_0=1$. Then $\Lambda$ *is* the functional constructed above.

So now we know: Coordinate functionals with respect to a Hamel basis need not be continuous.

Comment: A question concerning your construction : If you take any unbounded linear functional $\Lambda$, how do you know there is a $b$ such that $\Lambda b = 1$?

Comment: @roi_saumon If $\Lambda=0$ then $\Lambda$ is bounded. If $\Lambda\ne0$ there exists $x_0$ with $\Lambda x_0\ne0$, so $\Lambda(x_0/\Lambda x_0)=1$.